# When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument, String passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a string field poitable_type like "`Town`", "`Department`", "`Region`"
I'm trying to pass this string (`poitable_type`) as an argument to a method like :

```
update_counters("Towns")


def update_counters(poitable_type)
  count = Model.where(poitable_type: "poitable_type").count                          
  Model.update("#{poitable_type.downcase}_counter: #{count}")
end
```

But I get an error : When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument, `String` passed.

Comment: You passed a string to update. It expected a hash, just like your “where” call.

Comment: `Model.update("#{poitable_type.downcase}_counter" => count)` should work. But I wonder what is purpose of `update_counters`. `Model.update` will call update on all `Model` records and set same count for all `Model` records

Comment: @DaveNewton
I pass a string ("Town") in my method and my update must be :
Model.update(town_counter: count)

Comment: I'm trying : Model.update("#{poitable_type.downcase}_count": count) but return an error : TypeError: can't cast Hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling the update method wrong. The Active Record update method expects key-value pairs as arguments. You are trying to interpolate a string as an argument and expect it to behave like a hash.

That part should be changed like this.

```
Model.update("#{poitable_type.downcase}_counter": count)
```

That'll do the trick.